# Error inserting data ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hello guys im trying to create an account using ajax. everything works fine buy the problem is the age and contactnumber is not working on registration everydata can be inserted except for the age and contact number so i got a problem ,
my problem is the age and contact number can't inserted at the database
on 
index.php

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="createage">Age</label>
          <input id="createage" name="createage" class="form-control" type="text" >
      </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="createcontactnumber">Contact Number</label>
            <input id="createcontactnumber"
              name="createcontactnumber"
              class="form-control"
              oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
              type = "number" maxlength = "11"/>
        </div>
```

for register.js

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
$('#register').click(function(){

  var Bdate = document.getElementById('createbday').value;
  var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
  Q4A = ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
  var theBday = document.getElementById('createage');
  theBday.innerHTML = Q4A.val;


   var createusername = $('#createusername').val();
   var createpassword = $('#createpassword').val();
   var creategivenname = $('#creategivenname').val();
   var createmiddlename = $('#createmiddlename').val();
   var createlastname = $('#createlastname').val();
   var createbday = $('#createbday').val();
   var age = Q4A;
   var creategender = $('#creategender').val();
   var contactnumber = $('#createcontactnumber').val();
   var createaddress = $('#createaddress').val();
   var createcity = $('#createcity').val();
   $.ajax({
     type   : 'POST',
     data   :{createusername:createusername,
              createpassword:createpassword,
              creategivenname:creategivenname,
              createmiddlename:createmiddlename,
              createlastname:createlastname,
              createbday:createbday,
              age:age,
              creategender:creategender,
              contactnumber:contactnumber,
              createaddress:createaddress,
              createcity:createcity},
     url     :"insert.php",
    success : function(result){
      if(result)
      {
       $('#error').html("<span>Success Man</span>");
       $('#createusername').val('');
       $('#createpassword').val('');
       $('#creategivenname').val('');
       $('#createmiddlename').val('');
       $('#createlastname').val('');
       $('#createbday').val('');
       $('#createage').val('');
       $('#creategender').val('');
       $('#createcontactnumber').val('');
       $('#createaddress').val('');
       $('#createcity').val('');
      }
    }
   })
});
```

});

register.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "thaidatabase");

   $username = $_POST['createusername'];
   $password = $_POST['createpassword'];
   $givenname = $_POST['creategivenname'];
   $middlename = $_POST['createmiddlename'];
   $lastname = $_POST['createlastname'];
   $bday = $_POST['createbday'];
   $age = $_POST['createage'];
   $gender = $_POST['creategender'];
   $contactnumber = $_POST['createcontactnumber'];
   $address = $_POST['createaddress'];
   $city = $_POST['createcity'];

 mysqli_query($connect,"insert into account (username,password,givenname,middlename,lastname,bday,age,gender,contactnumber,address,city)
          values
          ('$username','$password','$givenname','$middlename','$lastname','$bday','$age','$gender','$contactnumber','$address','$city City')");


 mysqli_close($connect);


?>
```

Comment: Instead of image post your code here

Comment: Code in question please, not in a link and certainly not in an image.

Comment: sorry , i already update the post

Comment: Are you  getting values in server side ? Try echo in php code

Comment: i can get the value if i alert is on js

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing age as **age** attribute in POST request (JavaScript) and trying to read **createage** from _POST array in php.
Same for contactnumber.

The attribute sent must be received with the same name. Fix it, it must solve.

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "thaidatabase");

   $username = $_POST['createusername'];
   $password = $_POST['createpassword'];
   $givenname = $_POST['creategivenname'];
   $middlename = $_POST['createmiddlename'];
   $lastname = $_POST['createlastname'];
   $bday = $_POST['createbday'];

   //Edit This
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $gender = $_POST['creategender'];

   //Edit This
   $contactnumber = $_POST['contactnumber'];

   $address = $_POST['createaddress'];
   $city = $_POST['createcity'];

 mysqli_query($connect,"insert into account (username,password,givenname,middlename,lastname,bday,age,gender,contactnumber,address,city)
          values
          ('$username','$password','$givenname','$middlename','$lastname','$bday','$age','$gender','$contactnumber','$address','$city City')");


 mysqli_close($connect);


?>
```

Comment: im sorry but i can't actually get your point . what should i exactly do ?

Comment: I have added the fix can you change it ?

Comment: thanks man . but how come did the other input types saves and the age and contact number didnt ?

Comment: Others match attribute type . See when you are passing from js to server passing attribute must match in server.

Comment: you mean it the data that it got is the attribute ?

Comment: Vote cast with less that 15 reps are recorded but not change the publicy displayed at post it says

Comment: In js you have, see left hand side of each field
 
$.ajax({
     type   : 'POST',
     data   :{......
                 age:age,
                 .......
              contactnumber:contactnumber,
               ........},

In PHP you had $_POST[createage] and $_POST[createcontactnumber] it should be age and contact number